# When using the *sync functions in Node.js, what (if any) background operations continue to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

When using the Node.js *Sync functions (I understand you shouldn't, and the reasons why), what (if any) background processes continue to run?

For example, if I'm using http.createServer, and from one of the requests I call fs.writeFileSync(), will the server continue to serve new clients whilst that write is in progress (not just accept the connection, but process the entire request)? I.e. would writeFileSync() block the entire process, or just the current call chain?

Comment: I apologise for the poorly written question. Please feel free to edit, just please make sure you understand the question first. I'll be here for a while if you'd like clarification.

Comment: `*Sync` functions block entire process

Comment: Thanks for the reply vkurchatkin. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as such if that's the consensus (could you link to any documentation please?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the effect of using any *Sync function will just block the process as long-running javascript does. Running those *Sync, means that when the process is waiting for them to complete it just sits and do nothing. If you use the asynchronous counter part of those functions, when the process is waiting for them to complete and it will handle other pending events such as new http requests to be handled.

If you have http server running and you call a *Sync function, when the *Sync function is running all the new http requests in this time will be queued to be handled after your current  javascript and *Sync function has finished executing.

Here's a quote from [node documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

> In busy processes, the programmer is strongly encouraged to use the asynchronous versions of these calls. The synchronous versions will block the entire process until they complete--halting all connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Farid. Can you link to any documentation regarding this please?

Comment: Ack, thank you! I've been looking for that for quite some time.I can't post links of course, but that line is in the fs api docs.